# How to override Virtual Type class in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, overrides, dependency-injection

How to override VirtualType block in Magento 2, I want to override following virtual type block with my own block,

```
<virtualType name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
   <arguments>
       <argument name="catalogLayer" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search</argument>
   </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

So I tried to override it from my custom module `di.xml` like this,

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="My\Vendor\Block\Product\ListProductSearch" />
```

But it does not work.

So, **what is the proper way of overriding a virtual type class in Magento 2?**

Answer (score 18):

You have to use:

```
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ListProductSearch" />
```

as Raphael mentioned.

To make this singular block working properly, you need also to add `view/frontend/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml` file with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="search_result_list">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Why do you say you need the `setTemplate` action? I don't believe that's true. Setting a preference for the virtual type shouldn't affect the template setting that's already defined in the core layout XML.

Comment: @ScottBuchanan as far as template provided contains module. When answering this question this block contained template as `product/list.phtml` so using preference changed template to `Vendor_Module::product/list.phtml`

Comment: Ah, makes sense.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to override the virtual type in your example, you need to use:

```
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" type="My\Vendor\Block\Product\ListProductSearch" />
```

Instead of:

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="My\Vendor\Block\Product\ListProductSearch" />
```

In your example, you override the original type and not the virtual type, that's the reason why it's not working.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
Now I have tried the way you mentioned, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @nuwaus interesting, where is your `di.xml` located ?

Comment: my-plugin-dir/etc/di.xml

Comment: @nuwaus what if you move it to `etc/frontend/di.xml` ?

Comment: It still doesn't work :(

Comment: @nuwaus hmmmm I'm out of ideas here. I'll have to make some tests on my side and come back to you

Comment: Thank you, I will keep testing and keep you posted. thanks again!!

Comment: Overriding works now but it does  not return any products, do you have any idea?

Comment: @nuwaus could be caused by your custom rewrite ? What if you call the  parent methods instead?

Comment: what i did was made a copy of ListProduct class and change the class name and namespace. am i doing wrong?

Comment: @nuwaus your new class needs to extend the original `ListProduct` class

Comment: Yes, I have extended it like this 
`class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`

Comment: Ironically, this particular virtual type is completely pointless. The attribute it exists to inject (`$catalogLayer`) no longer exists and hasn't since before Magento 2.0.0  was even released.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how exactly the xml configurations are merged and sorted, but this type of problem usually comes down to sequence of the modules being loaded.

I would try adding sequence to your `module.xml` :

```
<sequence>
        <module name="Magento_CatalogSearch"/>
</sequence>
```

The preference described by Raphael above is working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just because I couldnt find it anywhere else

I did override:

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="My\Vendor\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" type="My\Vendor\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
```

So now, I can extend the base ListProduct.php Block either override functionality or extend it.

then the layout My/Vendor/view/frontend/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="search_result_list">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">My_Vendor::product/list.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

so in this layout update file Im also overriding the template and I can use the new methods added in my first preference.

Comment: I believe there's no need for the `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` preference. Just for the virtual type.