# How to override class Virtual Type class

Tags: magento2, overrides, plugin, preference, virtualtype

I saw this, but it don't work for me.

[How to override Virtual Type class in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142380/how-to-override-virtual-type-class-in-magento-2)

```
<virtualType name="categoryFilterList" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="filterableAttributes" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<virtualType name="searchFilterList" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="filterableAttributes" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search\FilterableAttributeList</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

How to override `Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList` ?

Plugin is creating successfully, but I'm unable to extend from parent class, as I need it's protected methods.

When I use preference - I'm facing with another issue. Magento is trying to create object from interface, which is impossible. As I understand it happen because it doesn't see

```
<arguments>
    <argument name="filterableAttributes" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search\FilterableAttributeList</argument>
</arguments>
```

The only way which is working for me - is overlapping config and setting sequence:

Copy config from above to my module and replace type to my own.

Comment: Did you use the name in the for section of the preference in your xml?

Comment: categoryFilterList? Yep, I tried this too. I didnt dive deep inside the code, but I think that name should be similar as class plus namespace