# Problem in overriding ListProduct on search results

Tags: magento2, override-block, search-result

We have overwritten Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct to be able to check if displayed products match a certain category.

We have set the preference in our module /etc.di.xml like this:

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct"
            type="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Catalog\ListProduct"/>
```

And we have overwritten the ListProduct Class like this:

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Catalog;

class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
protected $_customerSession;
protected $categoryFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
    array $data = [],
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
) {
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $postDataHelper,
        $layerResolver,
        $categoryRepository,
        $urlHelper,
        $data
    );
}

protected function _getProductCollection() {
...
}
...
```

## Problem:

The problem is that this class overrides ListProduct on all category pages except on search result page, where it still uses Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct and not te overwritten one.

How can we overwritte ListProduct class for search results page?

Answer (score 3):

May be this code is reason for it:

> vendor\magento\module-catalog-search\etc\frontend\di.xml

```
<virtualType name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="catalogLayer" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

please try here with your overridden class:

```
<virtualType name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Catalog\ListProduct">
```

Comment: I tried what you said and it does not work. It gives me a blank product page (just layered navigation block appears). 
However, thanks to your response I could reach this post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142380/how-to-override-virtual-type-class-in-magento-2 and this bug report https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13152 but I'm still unable to make it work. Everything that I try ends to a blank results page.

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For people wondering about this, Rutvee Sojitra solution works well !
on your module you need to create a di.xml in   /etc/frontend

and parse this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" type="VENDOR\MODULE-NAME\Block\CatalogSearch\ListProduct">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="catalogLayer" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem by using preference but not virtualtype

```
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" type="VENDOR\YOURMOUDLE\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
```