# How to override default search result in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, search, catalogsearch, elasticsearch

I want to override default Magento search result, as I am not getting idea from which file all data is displayed from which I want to filter the data.

Following are the requirements for overriding the result:

> I am working on a project where a single product is sold by multiple sellers currently using Magento default search.
>
> Following are my requirements
>
> 1. I have created an attribute called "model_number" all products with the same model number and name should appear once.
>
> **Example**:- If the product name is "Photo Frame", model number is 1234 and that product is sold by multiple sellers, then search result should display only that product which has minimum price. In addition, Product with the same name and different model number should also appear.

Comment: try this link may help you,https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/239711/problem-in-overriding-listproduct-on-search-results